# Why can we use Cauchy's integral formula in proving Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

So the Laurent series proof starts as follows.
Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ a set defined as $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid R_1<|z-c|<R_2\}$ where $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and let $f:S\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on $S$. Next we take some $z\in S$ and $R>0$ such that $B(z,R)\subseteq S$. Then we proceed to use the Cauchy integral formula to represent $f(z)$, but doesn't Cauchy integral formula only hold when $f$ is holomorphic on a simply connected set which $S$ clearly isn't?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $B(z,R)$ is simply connected and $f$ is holomorphic there.

Comment: I see, what confused me was the request that f:$\Omega$ $\to$ $\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on all of $\Omega$ and then for a path that encloses O$\subseteq$ $\Omega$ we can use the formula, but i guess you could pick r=R+$\epsilon$ such that B(z,R) $\subseteq$ B(z,r) and the formula holds, right? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: $B(z,R)$ doesn't help for finding the Laurent series at $c$ valid on $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Before using the Cauchy's integral formula, there are several steps utilizing contours. We start with the contour

[image]

Then the integral of $\frac{f(z)}{2\pi i(z-w)}$ over the upper half one yields $f(w)$, since we can find suitable simply-connected domain containing the contour and its inside, where $f$ is holomorphic. Also the integral over the lower contour is simply $0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem. Note that the line segments are actually  overlapped. Hence by cancelling integrals over the segments(which are reversed each other) the sum of upper and lower integrals become the integral over the below contour:

[image]

Hence we can say that $$f(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{C_1}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz-\int_{C_2}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz\right)$$ where $C_1, C_2$ are positively oriented circles which lies outside $w$ and inside $w$, respectively.

Comment: That makes  sense, thank you for clarification

Comment: As a remark, if $w$ is on the real axis, then we can take line segments away from the real axis.